# Process redirect standard output verbosity issue

Tags: c#, python, redirect, output, minecraft

I have a problem with reading data from process StandardOutput in C#. Here is what i have:

```
var hdd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
hdd.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe";
hdd.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar minecraft.jar";
hdd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
hdd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
hdd.Start();
while (!hdd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string data = hdd.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(">> " + data);
}
```

And here i have a second code, written in Python:

```
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe" -jar minecraft.jar'
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    print '>> ', line.strip()
    if line == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
```

The problem is, that both codes are working but in python, script prints about two times more information, than C# does.

C# output:

```
>> 229 recipes
>> 27 achievements
>> 
>> Starting up SoundSystem...
>> Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
>>     (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
>> OpenAL initialized.
```

Python's output:

```
>>  229 recipes
>>  27 achievements
2013-05-07 18:57:12 [CLIENT] [INFO] LWJGL Version: 2.4.2
>>
>>  Starting up SoundSystem...
>>  Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
>>  (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.or
g)
>>  OpenAL initialized.
>>
2013-05-07 18:57:14 [CLIENT] [INFO] Found animation info for: textures/blocks/lava_flow.txt
2013-05-07 18:57:14 [CLIENT] [INFO] Found animation info for: textures/blocks/water_flow.txt
2013-05-07 18:57:14 [CLIENT] [INFO] Found animation info for: textures/blocks/fire_0.txt
7 more lines similar to last 3 above
```

So we can clearly see, some of the informations are missing in C#. Specifically, the lines without ">> " from pythons output. 
Is there any way, I can catch those missing lines in C# ?

Comment: Could it be debug output that is captured by python? If you [download and run `DbgView`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) and start it up and leave it running while you run the C# program, do you see anything similar appearing in the DbgView window?

Comment: @Matthew Watson - Somehow I can't get any actual output. It says [4516] FMAPO: Debug function is disable (DbgView runned as admin, doesn't matter if I debug or run app manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (a guess) you should set `RedirectStandardError = true` too; it seems those additional information  is passing to Standard Error. You can use `ErrorDataReceived` for handling those lines.

Comment: Aww, I can't believe it was so simple :( Done and working, it was passing to StandardError indeed. Thank you !